# How do I connect the reference pins from a microcontroller's internal ADC?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design, adc, voltage-reference

I am using a TMS320F28379 microcontroller with these pins:

[image]

They are the references for the ADC. Can I leave them unconnected? Do I have to connect them to a specific value? In that case, how I know the reference value for my application for the internal ADC?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention if you plan to _use_ the ADC or not. Other than that, surely the manual would offer some hints. This seems like a specialized part with lots of extra ADC.

Answer (score 1):

Below statements are taken from [TMS320F2837xD Dual-Core Microcontrollers Technical Reference Manual](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhm8j/spruhm8j.pdf?ts=1698312568523&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTMS320F28379D) .

"Figure 11-24 shows the basic organization of the external voltage reference generation circuitry. A single
reference voltage generation source must be shared by all ADC modules. This minimizes reference voltage
mismatch between ADC modules. The reference voltage must then be buffered by a precision op-amp with
good bandwidth and low output impedance before being driven into the reference pin. A capacitor between
the high and low reference pins must be placed on the PCB as close to the pins as practical to help absorb
high-frequency currents. A series resistor (typically <1Ω) in series with this capacitor can be necessary to make
sure op-amp stability.
It is also possible to share two reference pins between one op-amp driver. This organization is shown in Figure
11-25. This gives slightly reduced performance compared to the case where each reference pin has a dedicated
op-amp buffer, but it can still be possible to achieve all ADC specifications in the data sheet."

You can see all the required details in reference manual.

[image]
[image]
[image]